# how do i import xmltodict on python 3.11.4(virtual venv) because rn it's giving me an error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, airflow, airflow-webserver

I'm trying to make a project on vs code using airflow and here is the code.

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
import pendulum

import requests
import xmltodict
#decorator creation
@dag (
    dag_id = "podcast_summary2",
    schedule_interval = "@daily",
    start_data= pendulum.datetime(2022,5,31),
    catchup=False

)
def podcast_summary2():
    @task()
    def get_episodes():
        data = requests.get("https://marketplace.org/feed/podcast/marketplace/")
        #feed = xmltodict.parse(data.text)
        episodes = feed["rss"]["channel"]["item"]
        print(f"Found{len(episodes)} episodes.")
        return episodes
    podcast_episodes = get_episodes()


summary = podcast_summary2()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cftDV.png)

I was expecting it to import xmltodict, but it won't on this python version but it will for python 3.9

Comment: if you don't install it in the virt env ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever python interpreter you use you need to install the `xmltodict` package for that. Or choose an interpreter environment that already has the `xmltodict` package installed. Obviously you don't.

Also need to pay attention to the use of **Python** extensions to execute scripts (`Run Python File`).

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters*